# i am having this problem when i try to run flutter as a desktop app

Tags: flutter, android-studio, caching, mobile, flutter-dependencies

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Th29.png)

> i am having a problem to run my project as a desktop app facing this problem in image added i tried all the suggestion in the internet but nothing work i changed the flutter version up and down i deleted all caches file i tried flutter clean and invalidate cache and restart also but didnt solve can you help me

**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well the image being not displayed in gmail is not a flutter issue

On your computer, go to Gmail.
In the top right, click Settings Settings and then See all settings.
Scroll down to the "Images" section.
Click Always display external images.
At the bottom of the page, click Save Changes.

Comment: i added the correct image